# Content-Security-Policy Header vs. CSRF Token and login.html

Tags: javascript, security, html-entities

My company would use the current version of the [Content-Security-Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) header.

We have problems with inline JavaScript and would not use MD5 checksums with the policy.

Eg:

- CSRF Token support

https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript

- the login.html template

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/templates/login.html#L15

- Maybe other source code files

Both the CSRF suggestion and the login implementation uses inline javascript.

Exist best practices to solve the problems?
Without ESI how could I include the CSRF token in a separate Javascript file (access the Craft environment variables)?

Is it possible to add the header only for none CP requests?

Thanks

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, you want a CSP that explicitly doesn't allow any inline JavaScript, correct? `Is it possible to add the header only for none CP requests?` You can certainly only add the CSP headers for front-end requests via `.htaccess`.